# Прямая речь в тексте

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Вопрос следующий: надо ли мысли в авторском тексте оформлять, как прямую речь?
Предложение следующее: Я пошел пешком до метро "Красносельская", а в голове постоянная мысль: "Если я занимаюсь арматуростроением уже более 25 лет, то сколькими же годами должны быть измерены те знания, которые были озвучены Ромуальдом Ромуальдовичем в нашей беседе?"

Answer (score 1):

Да, это прямая речь, читаем [здесь](http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-057.htm).